# Bluetooth on Raspberry Pi Zero W, using buildroot

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, buildroot

I'm trying to get the onboard Broadcom bluetooth working in a Buildroot 2017.08 built linux on the Raspberry Pi **Zero W**. It's not showing me the adapter. Bluetooth USB dongles do work.

Things I've already done:

- Added rpi-bt-firmware
- Added Bluez-tools and Bluez5-utils
- Kernel compiled with all sorts of Bluetooth support
- Loaded bluetooth modules: bluetooth, bnep, btbcm, hci_uart
- rfkill list (shows no bluetooth devices)
- rfkill unblock bluetooth (just in case)

After boot I'm manually starting bluetoothd followed by bluetoothctl.
when I type "power on", "list" or "show" it does not give me any bluetooth controllers.

The hardware is working, on the same system I have Debian Jessie working fine with the bluetooth.

Also, given that USB bluetooth dongles work, I think the kernel is OK too.

- What could possibly be the problem here??
- Anything I could try to troubleshoot??
- Anything I could install or add to make it work??

Anything is welcome at this point! :)

**UPDATE**

I have it working by running `hciattach /dev/ttyAMA0 bcm43xx 921600 flow -` at start-up. However, I have barely a clue what's going on here. Proper explanation will count as an answer.

I have also removed console=/dev/ttyAMA0 from the cmdline.txt, not sure though if that was necessary.

Comment: is working now when reboot your rpi then opening automatically onboard bluetooth? 

I select  all bluez/5 items under buildroot, modied output/image/rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt , output/target/etc/profile 

after connect to rpi via ssh, then display "no hciattach command found" something

Answer (score 2):

`hciattach` attaches serial HCI devices via UART to Bluez stack https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-hciattach/.
In your case the serial Broadcom HCI adapter is at /dev/ttyAMA0, so the command your run attaches it to Bluez as a bcm43xx HCI adapter.

Its probably done the same in your Debian Jessie setup.